# Column names of a data.frame separated with comma

Tags: r

I want to get column names of a `data.frame` separated with `comma (,)`. I remembered I got this result in past but now forgot the command.

```
df<- data.frame(x=1:10, y=11:20)
names(df)
```

**Output**

```
"x" "y"
```

**Desired Output**

```
c("x", "y")
```

Comment: Are you looking for `dput(names(df))` perhaps?

Comment: This is what I need. I remember I used this command in past but forgot. Would you mind to change your comment to answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to get exactly what it sounds like you're asking for (without knowing exactly how you plan to use this information) is to use `dput`:

```
dput(names(df))
# c("x", "y")
```

By extension, without fussing with `paste`:

```
x <- capture.output(dput(names(df)))
x
# [1] "c(\"x\", \"y\")"
cat(x)
# c("x", "y")
```

---

Although @Jilber deleted his answer, you can use `shQuote` to go from what he had started with to the output of "x" above:

```
paste("c(", paste(shQuote(names(df)), collapse = ", "), ")", sep = "")
# [1] "c(\"x\", \"y\")"
```